# Why the inside div(header_logo) pulling down header too

Tags: html

[The image states my question clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggJEL.jpg)

[Code.io coding page][2]

**codepen.io/sachoosaini/post/why-the-header_logo-div-pull-down-the-header-when-i-change-margin-like-10px** the second one is link to css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because of the collapsed margins , see more here > [collapse margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

one fix for this would be to add `overflow:auto` to the `#header` ( parent div )

see snippet below

and also, next time you post a question, visit [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post your code here, not on an external site

```css
body {
  background-color: #454343;
  margin:0;

}

#header {
  width: 961px;
  height: 184px;
  background-color: #D54C17;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header_logo {
  width: 361px;
  height: 133px;
  background-color: #986c6c;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="header_logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well i don't know how to use website. But i will try to make sure next time i will use the code the here..... You created it such a normal way. I am getting totally confused with small things. Thank you for helping me out

Comment: @SachinSaini if this answer worked for you. please rate it as accepted

Comment: i did brother. I have to get though this website to learn how to use it